# Altium Designer - Create keepout based on board outline

Tags: altium

Is there a method in Altium Designer where I can immediately create keepout lines on each edge of my board? My board shape has a complex design which is why I am looking for this method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Design -> Board Shape -> Create Primitives From Board Shape.

Then select what layer you want to create the primitives on and how thick you want the outline to be.

I don't have access to Altium at the moment so this is from memory. I use it all the time, though I use a separate mechanical layer specifically for the board outline (usually Mechanical Layer 6 renamed to "BOARD_OUTLINE").

Answer (score 2):

What @DerStrom8 had suggested is correct.  +1 to him.  I'd like to elaborate a little.

- Go to *Design → Board Shape → Create Primitives from Board Shape*
- Pick layer and width in the dialog.  Click OK.
  Altium will create a track around the PCB.  This isn't the keep-out yet.
- Select this new track around the outline of the PCB.
- Go to *Tolls →  Convert →  [Convert Selected Primitives to Keepouts](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-cmd-converttokeepoutconverttokeepout-ad)*.
  Now you have the keep-out around the board outline.

At the time of writing, I'm running Altium 20.1.10 .

#### added:

Related function in Altium: [Board Outline Clearance](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-dlg-boardoutlineclearance-frameboard-outline-clearance-ad) .
This kind of clearance is faster to set up, because everything is defined in one rule.  It creates a clearance with a constant width for all levels.  It doesn't create an actual keep out object in the layout.

I used the board outline clearance rule for setting up the minimum clearance.   Then I created keepouts on the board outline where I needed larger clearances.